# Read data from a text file using Java

Tags: java, file-io, fileinputstream

I need to read a text file line by line using Java. I use `available()` method of `FileInputStream` to check and loop over the file. But while reading, the loop terminates after the line before the last one. *i.e.*, if the file has 10 lines, the loop reads only the first 9 lines. 
Snippet used :

```
while(fis.available() > 0)
{
    char c = (char)fis.read();
    .....
    .....
}
```

Comment: You should use [BufferedReader](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) to read a file line by line.

Answer (score 14):

You should not use `available()`. It gives no guarantees what so ever. From the [API docs of `available()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29):

> Returns an **estimate** of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next invocation of a method for this input stream.

You would probably want to use something like

```
try {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("infilename"));
    String str;
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null)
        process(str);
    in.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

(taken from http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/ReadLinesFromFile.html)

Comment: +1 to this. This is my preferred approach too. However, the in.close() should probably reside in a finally block.

Comment: I know. That however, requires another `try...catch` since `close()` itself may through `IOException`. Becomes sort of ugly for a minimal example.

Comment: Yep. Was typing an answer halfway myself when I decided to scrape the try/catch (you beat me to the answer though).

Answer (score 11):

How about using Scanner? I think using Scanner is easier

```
     private static void readFile(String fileName) {
       try {
         File file = new File(fileName);
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
         while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
           System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
         }
         scanner.close();
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
     }
```

[Read more about Java IO here](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/scanning-text-with-java.util.scanner-3.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to read line-by-line, use a [`BufferedReader`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html). It has a `readLine()` method which returns the line as a String, or null if the end of the file has been reached. So you can do something like:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
 // Do something with line
}
```

(Note that this code doesn't handle exceptions or close the stream, etc)

Answer (score 3):

```
String file = "/path/to/your/file.txt";

try {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
    String line;
    // Uncomment the line below if you want to skip the fist line (e.g if headers)
    // line = br.readLine();

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        // do something with line

    }
    br.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("ERROR: unable to read file " + file);
    e.printStackTrace();   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try FileUtils from org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils, [try downloading jar from here](http://commons.apache.org/io/download_io.cgi)

and you can use the following method:
FileUtils.readFileToString("yourFileName");

Hope it helps you..

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code skipped the last line was because you put `fis.available() > 0` instead of `fis.available() >= 0`

Answer (score 1):

In **Java 8** you could easily turn your text file into a List of Strings with streams by using `Files.lines` and `collect`:

```
private List<String> loadFile() {
    URI uri = null;
    try {
        uri = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("example.txt").toURI();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to load file.", e);
    }
    List<String> list = null;
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(uri))) {
        list = lines.collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to load file.", e);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//The way that I read integer numbers from a file is...

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Practice
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("cards.txt"));

        int times = input.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i < times; i++)
        {
            int numbersFromFile = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(numbersFromFile);
        }




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this just a little search in Google

```
import java.io.*;
class FileRead 
{
   public static void main(String args[])
  {
      try{
    // Open the file that is the first 
    // command line parameter
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
    // Get the object of DataInputStream
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String strLine;
    //Read File Line By Line
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
      // Print the content on the console
      System.out.println (strLine);
    }
    //Close the input stream
    in.close();
    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
      System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read text. Unfortunately examples like this get copied again and again so can you can remove it from your example. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using **java.io.BufferedReader** like this.

```
java.io.BufferedReader br = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(new java.io.FileInputStream(fileName)));
String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
//Process the line
}
br.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, buffering should be used for better performance. 
Use BufferedReader OR byte[] to store your temp data.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

user scanner it should work

```
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
         while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
           System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
         }
         scanner.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ReadFileUsingFileInputStream {

/**
* @param args
*/
static int ch;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("C://text.txt");
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        try {
            while((ch = fileInputStream.read())!= -1){
                stringBuffer.append((char)ch);  
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("File contents :");
    System.out.println(stringBuffer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FilesStrings {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
    InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(fis);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(input);
    String data;
    String result = new String();

    while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
        result = result.concat(data + " ");
    }

    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? The answer contains code, please add some explanations. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    File file = new File("Path");

    FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);  

    while((ch=reader.read())!=-1)
    {
        System.out.print((char)ch);
    }
```

This worked for me

Answer (score -3):

Simple code for reading file in JAVA:

```
import java.io.*;

class ReadData
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File("<put your file path here>"));
        while(true)
        {
            int n=fr.read();
            if(n>-1)
            {
                char ch=(char)fr.read();
                System.out.print(ch);
            }
        }
    }
}
```